# Kinect SDK 1.7 and OpenNi 2.2

Tags: kinect, openni, kinect-sdk

I am Trying to use OpenNi 2.2 and Nite 2.2 for skeleton tracking. On the other hand I want to use Kinect SDK 1.7 for Speech processing. Is it possible? I am trying to use this code. But it fails.

```
Init(){
openni::Device device;

openni::Status rc = openni::OpenNI::initialize();

openni::Status rc = device.open(openni::ANY_DEVICE);

nite::NiTE::initialize();

INuiSensor * NuiSensor;

HRESULT hr;

hr = NuiCreateSensorByIndex(0, &NuiSensor);

hr = pNuiSensor->NuiInitialize(NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_AUDIO); 

if (NULL == pNuiSensor || FAILED(hr))

printf("No ready Kinect found!\n");}
```

If this is not possible then why?? please explain.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible! See [kinect-i blogspot](http://kinect-i.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-install-and-use-openni-microsoft.html)'s post on how to do this. It uses a bride you can view [here](https://code.google.com/p/kinect-mssdk-openni-bridge/). *However* you need to use the SDK 1.6, but that sounds like it will be ok for you since you aren't using Fusion (see [What's New](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663803.aspx#SDK_1pt7) to see what updates there were in 1.7)

Comment: I have used the bridge but having some problem to initalize the audio